# Why does printing parent node of a node returns parent + child nodes?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Given a start position, I can find a node by passing it to `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.NodeFinder` class.

```
NodeFinder node = new NodeFinder(root, m.getSourceStart(), m.getSourceEnd() - m.getSourceStart() + 1);
ASTNode n = node.getCoveredNode();
```

Let assume that this node has a parent and get the node's parent `n.getParent();` does anyone know why it prints out the parent node and the node?

For instance we know the starting point of `foo()` in `bar.foo()` so if I do `System.Out.Println(n.getParent().toString());` it prints `bar.foo()`. Shouldn't it print only `bar`?

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is expected.

In this example:

```
foo.bar
```

`bar` is a `SimpleName` and its parent is a `QualifiedName` that contains both `foo` and `bar`.  So the parent node will contain more than one AST node and calling `toString` on it will print out all of this node's children.

Comment: Ok thanks. So is there a way to access the qualified name by itself?

Comment: The qualified name is "foo.bar".  I think you are asking to access only "foo", when you are given "bar".  The answer is yes.  If you start with "bar", you need to get its parent, which is of type QualifiedName.  Then you need to call "getQualifier()" on it.  You will need to call this recursively to handle the case of "foo.bar.baz.bop".

Comment: Thank you for your insight. The getQualifier was really helpful:
ASTNode n = node.getCoveredNode().getParent();
if (n instanceof Expression) {
    Expression exp = (Expression) n;
    if (exp instanceof MethodInvocation) {
        MethodInvocation m = (MethodInvocation) exp;
        System.out.println(Signature.getQualifier(m.toString()));
    }}